# Event.target.ParentNode() is considering the all previous interacted target elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement to do list using javascript.Here I am performing two operations by clicking the to do list elements.

1. Mark as Complete
2. Remove list elements

Here the issue is after performing Mark as Complete Operation, if i perform Remove operation the marked list element also removed. I dont want that to be removed.

```
let popup = document.querySelector('.PopUp');
let completebtn = document.querySelector('.Complete');
let removebtn = document.querySelector('.remove');
let canclebtn = document.querySelector('.cancle');

allItemRows.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   
    if(hasClass(e.target,'item-name')){
        popup.style.display = 'block';
        e.stopPropagation();

        completebtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
            e.target.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            popup.style.display = 'none';     
        });

        removebtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
            e.target.parentNode.remove();
            popup.style.display = 'none';
            changeSerialNo();
        });

        canclebtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
            popup.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
});
    
function hasClass(elem, className){
    return elem.classList.contains(className);
}
```

**Code Pen : https://codepen.io/tmuthu/pen/XWRpdPQ**

Comment: can you also show your html? In fact, why not just make a testable snippet. thx

Comment: codepen link added. thx.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: It seems like you have to rethink the event listener attached to the allItemRows variable, if possible, don't have it nested. The issue is not only happening with the "Mark as complete" button, it's also occurring with the "Cancel" button. So clearly the elements being clicked on are being saved somewhere and when you fire the "remove" button, the element that was first clicked on plus the element you want to remove will both go.

Comment: I removed the Nested event listeners. Now that is working fine!!!. I am not sure why that nested event listeners are causing the issue. Can you explain about this issue. @CesarCorrechel. thx.